# mod rewrite apache subdomain www to non www

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I just find it hard and not sure how to use mod_rewrite for my domains and sub-domains.

all I want to do is to redirect the following:

1- **from either www or non www domain to another domain**

```
www.domain.net || domain.net --> mydomain.com
```

2- **force www sub-domain to non www sub-domain **

```
www.sub.domain.com --> sub.domain.com
```

I tried the following code for the 1st part and it worked, but got me in trouble causing some conflict with sub-domains.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I believe there is a fix, but not sure how!!

I went through many articles, but didn't find the right solution.

any idea how to do that??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.sub\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks. The domain.net to domain.com with/without www did the job. However, the subdomain with www to non www didn't work. any idea how to get it right?

Comment: I didn't test that on my own web server but maybe the `www\.` should just be `www.` no \ same for `sub\.`.  Play around with it you should be able to get it working. :)